# Cannot install custom R package with rJava

Tags: r, devtools, rjava

I'm attempting to write an R package that uses rJava, and I'm trying to get started with it. With devtools, i'll run the `install()` command on my package, but I'll get the following error:

```
* installing *source* package 'WRCHSVM' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'WRCHSVM':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/mhmdm/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/WRCHSVM'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

The error suggests my Java and R architectures are not matching. However I can assure you, I only have 64 bit Java and my current R session is also 64 bit. What gives? Thanks

A little update: so it appears to work fine with the `install and restart` button in RStudio. However, RStudio isn't a part of my workflow. Would be awesome if I can get it working with devtools

Comment: Every answer I've seen for this error message says that the issue is 32-bit Java on a 64-bit OS. What does `java -d64 -version` at the command prompt say?

Comment: try using `devtools::install(INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")`. There is probably somewhere in Tools -> Global Options where you can set this permanently

Comment: @neilfws I'm getting the following:

java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: @chinsoon12 that didn't do it :/

Comment: do you have access to the registry? you might need to navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion to see if your 1.8 is there. if not you will need to reinstall and make sure that registry is updated

Comment: Similar problem here.    
I have 64-bit Java (both JDK and JRE), and 64-bit R. 

I am having a problem installing a package from github that yields a slightly different error:  
`LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` 
I tried different versions of rJava, I have `JAVA_HOME` set to my `jre` directory (I also read that some folks tried with it set to blank -- tried, didn't work).  
I can load rJava -- it's just I keep getting this error when I try to install my github package.